# while using '$?' expression in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a simple bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

ls xyzzy.345 > /dev/null 2>&1
status =' echo $?'
echo "status is $status"
```

which finds the file `xyzzy.345` and logs the result to `/dev/null`. But when it comes to the line  `status =' echo $?'`, I get this error:

```
status: Unknown job: = echo $?
```

But `echo $?` is recognized in the terminal.

Can anybody help me? My OS is ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Have you tried the || and && syntax to check if the command was ok or failed? Have you tried a if to check if the file exists instead of checking the return value from ls?

Answer (score 15):

You have an extra space between `status` and the `=`. Bash [variable assignments](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters) need to have no space between the name and the `=` sign:

```
status='echo $?'
```

What you've written is calling the `status` command with the single argument `=' echo $?'`.

---

All of that said, I think that what you probably want to write is:

```
status=$?
```

That stores the value of `$?` into the `status` variable.

If your real code is a little more complicated and you want to run a command and save the value, use either of these:

```
status=`echo "$?"`
status=$(echo "$?")
```

These use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) to access the output of a command.